# Transform X to get Y such that Y has a Uniform(0,1) distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function, uniform-distribution

A random variable $X$ has the PDF

$f_X(x) = \frac{x - 1}{2}, \ 1 < x < 3$

Find a monotone function $u(x)$ such that the variable $Y = u(X)$ has the distribution $Uniform(0,1)$.

Comment: Any thoughts to share on the problem? If this is homework, consider adding the `self-study` tag and read the tag wiki.

Comment: I don't have any valuable ideas. I tried to reverse the multiplication and addition, but I cannot find a correct transformation.

Comment: Please explore https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+integral+transform* for answers.

Comment: Google 'probability integral transform'.

Comment: Ah - that's very helpful.  I did not know this before, so I did not know what to search on Google.  I just learned that the CDF of a continuous random variable has a uniform distribution! Thank you!

Comment: Can I solve this to provide a solution?

Comment: MSE you can answer your own question (I have reopened so that you can choose to do so), though it's possible that it's already answered on site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the probability integral transform, the CDF of $X$ has a uniform distribution.  Thus,

$Y = u(X) = \frac{1}{4}(X - 1)^2$

Comment: Could you show how you did this?

Comment: It seems like all we did was set Y equal to the CDF of x here over the interval $1 \leq x \leq F^{-1}(x)$. 

Of course, the probability integral transform says we set $F(x) = y$. So I suppose this makes sense.. just seems incomplete somehow.